# Does anyone know how to see the cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so?

Tags: linux, cmake, installation, ubuntu-18.04, setup.py

[image]

I am trying to do some project and I'm stuck.

I want to see how it is coded inside the pydense script but pydense script is
not a normal python script file! That green files all of them is cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  and they came out when I did the command "python setup.py" CMAKE install things.

I don't know how to open that thing. I need to see the code inside that files.
Can anyone tell me how to see the linux-gnu.so script file?? Any great advice.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: this is not a script file, you are trying to look at a native library, this is a shared library probably written in C or C++ and compiled...

Comment: I figured out that file was compiled CMake   from C++ file. So I need to see the original C++ file.! Thank you!!